# Short story about a man who imprints his consciousness to a machine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I remember reading a short story about a man who imprints his consciousness to a robot in order to achieve immortality. The robot becomes more and more powerful and survives past the existence of humans. The robot/man consciousness decides to create a world based on his memories of his life as a human. The robot is in essence God.

Comment: Can you recall any other details? When did you read this, for example?

Comment: Obligatory: are you sure this isn't The Last Question by Asimov, which this bears some resemblances to.

Comment: I'm positive this isn't "The Last Question" by Asimov although it was likely inspired by it.

As I recall, the robot is the last intelligent being and creates a world out of loneliness.

Comment: It sounds very similar to this 4chan post. http://imgur.com/gallery/NMPyl

Comment: This is a long shot and it's not a short story but the final book in Asimov's _Foundation_ series has something similar to this. You may find the answer within the universe it shares with his Robot series.

Answer (score 2):

It is the book "Mind Transfer" (1988) by the author Janet Asimov.

From [this review](https://www.publishersweekly.com/978-0-8027-6748-6):

> Using the background of husband Isaac's classic robot stories of the '40s and '50s, Janet Asimov considers the possibilities and problems of the title technique: imprinting human minds on robot brains to give the aging and ill a second life. Naturally, there is a backlash, the rabid conservative movement called biofundamentalism. The novel is structured around the life, death and subsequent robotic existence of Adam Durant, who is born into a dynasty torn between ""bioeffers'' and pioneering roboticists. In a story crowded with incident (settling another star system, terrorist bombings, hyperdrive innovations, alien encounters), the interesting question of a robotic culture that doesn't imitate its human parent is not developed. Also appealing as an idea is the outlined family chronicle with robots as relatives, but the bland characters and rushed, chaotic plot weaken its impact.

Comment: Could you provide some more details on what exactly in the book you suggest are similar to the question?